# Validate the name of a person in php

Tags: php, preg-match

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Regex to validate names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5105244/regex-to-validate-names)

I am developing a site.In that i want to validate the users name that is their first name and last name.Names will also contain letters like ó

I now validate using

```
if(!preg_match("/[a-zA-Z]+$/",$value))
{
echo "Invalid characters";
}
```

How do i validate the special characters? Friends i meant special characters like ó . I want this available in the name . But take off the letters like @,#,$

Comment: Names are very complex. You'd be best off just checking that *something* has been entered. A white list won't work.

Comment: Regex ain't suitable for first and last names, poor *Mr. O'Shea*. Just strip off harmful stuff. FWIW, [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923729/checking-for-diacritics-with-a-regular-expression).

Comment: @Quentin i would like to show their name to other users how could i show if it contain letters like @,#,$ etc.

Comment: @harikrishnan.n0077 — `<p>My name is J@k Ca$h</p>`. (Odds aren't too unfavourable that a rapper somewhere really is using that name).

Comment: Who says that someone didn't name their child using $, #, @ etc? People are crazy and they do dumb stuff all day long, you can't rule anything out and as Quentin said - names are *very* complex. There is no rule about naming someone, you can literally be named using 25 000 spaces.

Comment: There *are* rules about naming people, but they aren't globally implemented rules, so you can't make your system depend on them.

Comment: You can probably disallow characters like `@` and `#`, 99.999999% of people probably won't have those in their names. Anything beyond that is pretty open though, names contain anything from `-` over `'` to `ó` and `雅`.

Comment: See what facebook does it does not allow @ # $ and allows ó .What about that?

Comment: So you want a regex that allows anything but `@#$`? `/^[^@#$]+$/`