# regular expression negation

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

In my current regular expression, I am negating digits:

```
$(function(){
  $("#somewhat").bind("keyup",
   function(event) {
     var regex = /^[\D]*$/;
     alert(regex.test($("#somewhat").val()));
  });
});
```

What I have in my mind is to add some special characters on which I should negate, **!@#$%^&*()_+=<>.?/~`:;"** , and leaving dash, apostrophe ( **-'** ) to the valid list. I'm still kind of dizzy on this regular expression thing. To test with, I added **+** on the regex,

```
var regex = /^[\D+]*$/;
```

When I test it, the alert box returns TRUE, which is not I am expecting.

Comment: What is the content of the HTML element you're matching?

Comment: I am trying to validate name, I can't seem to use `/[a-zA-Z]*$/` since I am accepting other letters in European country such as Germany. So I go for the other way around in which I come up to negation.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888838/regular-expression-for-validating-names-and-surnames

Comment: Also to test your regex have you tried http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ allows you to hover your mouse of each portion of the regex and it explains in plain english what it will do

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside [ ] please add all the characters you don't want to allow.

```
/^((?![\d!@#$%^&*()_+=<>.?/~`:;"]).)*$/
```

But can we rely on negating given characters ? because user will be able to enter any character other than these. If you want to allow non-English characters, I would suggest you to use Unicode ranges

see this : http://kourge.net/projects/regexp-unicode-block

Answer (score 0):

`[\D+]` means "any character that is `+`, or that is not a digit"; so it's actually equivalent to plain old `\D` or `[\D]`, since `+` itself isn't a digit.

To get the meaning of "any character that is neither `+` nor a digit", you'd have to write `[^\d+]`.

(`\D` or `[\D]` is equivalent to `[^\d]`, but its negative-ness doesn't extend beyond that.)