# Get all alphabets in a string of words using regex (including spaces)

Tags: php, regex

How would I extract all alpha characters (including space) like for example:

`@john camel07 st.doe!`

where I only want to get `john camel stdoe`.

I tried using the regex from this [another SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11531686/regular-expression-for-all-letters-in-all-alphabets-with-spaces-exept-anything-e) but it does not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$re = "/[^a-zA-Z ]+/"; 
$str = "@john camel07 st.doe!"; 
$subst = ""; 

$result = preg_replace($re, $subst, $str);
```

You can simply replace by `empty string` all non alpha and space characters.See demo.

https://www.regex101.com/r/rL8wP1/7

Comment: You could add a `+` after the character class, so it can replace multiple adjacent characters at once.

Comment: @vks What about `"/[^a-z\s]+/i"`. better?

Comment: @Tushar yeah a better one :) there's no need for space after `\s`.But this will also replace `newlines`

Answer (score 1):

If your data contains unicode, this should work a bit better:

```
echo preg_replace("/[^[:alpha:][:space:]]/ui", '', '@john camel07 st.doe!');
```

Borrowed with a change from https://stackoverflow.com/a/659030/1935500