# Regular Expression for validating full name in capital letters (unicode characters included)?

Tags: regex, validation, unicode, google-forms

I am creating a Google Form and am using the data validation feature in the text/paragraph text option. I need to validate the names of people. The names need to be filled in **capital letters** and will possibly have a **variable number of words**. The name could be '**FIRSTNAME LASTNAME**' or '**FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME LASTNAME**' or '**FIRSTNAME MIDDLENAME1 MIDDLENAME2 LASTNAME**', etc.

Another thing is that some of the names include characters from the **Turkish and Portuguese alphabet** and in the future, could include characters from the **Cyrillic alphabet** also. How can I include all such possibilities in the regex? It would also be great if an explanation could be given for the expressions used.

PS: I checked [Regular expression for validating names and surnames?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888838/regular-expression-for-validating-names-and-surnames) but 1. It is only valid for Name Surname, and 2. It includes small case letters as well.

Comment: Why do they need to be in capitals? Most people don't write their name in caps.

Comment: Because the names are for business cards printed and we use capital letters on them. The output file will go directly to the printer.

Comment: fair enough. but couldn't you also just accept mixed case and then convert to upper case internally? (ie whatever language you're using the regex with would presumably have a `strtoupper()` or similar?)

Answer (score 1):

One of these might give you some idea's -

```
 # --------------------
 # To capture names, first/last name required
 # \s*\p{Lu}+(?:\s+\p{Lu}+)*\s+\p{Lu}+\s*
 # --------------------

 \s*                       # some boundry                  (optional)
 ( \p{Lu}+ )               # (1), upper case first name    (required) 
 (                         # (2), upper case middle names  (optional)
      (?: \s+ \p{Lu}+ )*
 )
 \s+                       # some boundry                  (required) 
 ( \p{Lu}+ )               # (3), upper case last name     (required) 
 \s*                       # some boundry                  (optional)


 # --------------------
 # Or, if no boundry and only first name required
 # \p{Lu}+(?:\s+\p{Lu}+)*
 # --------------------

 \p{Lu}+ 
 (?: \s+ \p{Lu}+ )*


 # --------------------
 # Or, if no boundry and first/last name required
 #\p{Lu}+(?:\s+\p{Lu}+)+
 # --------------------

 \p{Lu}+ 
 (?: \s+ \p{Lu}+ )+
```