# Surname regular expression

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a good regular expression for people's Surname.

It should be valid if a Surname is:

**abcd**

**abcd'efg**

**abcd-efg**

**abcd, .efg**

etc...

I also need to test if symbols do not repeat... so for example:

**abcd''efg**

**abcd-',**

Are invalid but the one:

**abcd, .efg**

Can be valid.

At the moment I just created this:

```
^[a-z .',-_]+$
```

And now I'm trying to check for all the double symbols but I cannot go ahead successfully.

Comment: How is `abcd'efg` valid but `abcd"efg` isn't?

Comment: single ' is valid, multiple ' not...

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo: ... and `"` is a single character.

Comment: Thanks @AmalMurali, yes indeed `abcd"efg` has single double quote

Comment: I didn't wrote '**"**' but a double "**''**". Now does it make sense?

Comment: ok then how is `abcd, .efg` valid but `abcd-',` isn't?

Comment: Or better, double apostrophe is invalid, single quotation marks is invalid. single apostrophe is valid.

Comment: Because I need **Mc'Millan, .jr** to be valid and no other alternatives.

Comment: We are talking about why, why and why... but no one write a single line of regex here... I don't need regex suggestions I just need to solve my regex.

Comment: Seems like you guys doen't have 2 different keyboard keys with ' and " to continue talking about it...

Comment: People get many answers to a question that are easy to understand and have all the logic/rules clear. Do you seriously believe you question meets this criteria?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If after reading [this insightful post by Amal Murali](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25265515/3622940) and you still want to do this with a regex, please see this:

```
/^(?![^'\-_\n]*['\-_][^'\-_\n]*['\-_])[a-z .',-_]+$/m
```

[View a regex demo!](http://regex101.com/r/gN5jU6/2)

Comment: And this doesn't match `abcd"efg` as valid (single double quote that is). Moreover `And now I'm trying to check for all the double symbols but I cannot go ahead successfully.` is matched using this regex as valid surname.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bad idea. There is no international list of allowed characters that people could use in their names. Some surnames even contain Unicode symbols — it will not be possible to write a regex that would perfectly validate all of them correctly. Even if you can come up with a regex, it might be too generic that it wouldn't be effective.

Read this article for why you shouldn't be doing this: [Falsehoods Programmers Believe About Names](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/)

Comment: I just need to create the regex I wrote above... Even if it is a bad idea. Thanks

Comment: I'll just quote [John](http://stackoverflow.com/a/888902/1438393): "*Step back and ask yourself what you are actually trying to accomplish. Then try to accomplish it without making any assumptions about what people's surnames are, or what they mean.*".