# How to store persons name in a record table

Tags: database-design

### Intro

Damn, this is harder then I thought.

Some people have **camel-case** names like `McDonald` or `O'Ferncher`, and some do not have **double-barrelled** name, but **hyphenated name** like `Bowes-Lyon` or just **given name**, like `Honovi Hohnihhohkaiyohos` ( Strong High Backed Wolf ). In some culture spaces like:

- Portuguese you have **more then 1** family name and **more then 1** first name (by default).
- Russia you have middle name (**patronymic**), that is **obligatory**.

In some places you have gender inequality and to formally address a person you need to use **prefix**, like: `Sir` (where gender can be male, female and in-between). And yes, prefix changes depending on the persons age.

Like this is not enough - people can and will get married (this occurs pretty often)(thy might do this multiple times), and it is a **default** custom for **at least one** partner to change their **family name**. In most places people can change their name or at least given name.
[image]

### More details

*This is not important if you want to answer the question, just giving a hint what I'm trying to do.*

Tables where I want to store the names are in xml and [appengine datastore](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine) with [twig](http://code.google.com/p/twig-persist/) object store interface (I use twig among other things, for it enables me to compile schema). Data itself can come form various places and probably there exists a case where old name is used (so - storing multiple names).

My best guess is:

```
@XmlAttribute @Key protected Long id;
@XmlElement(required = true) final protected List<String> lastName;
@XmlElement(required = false) protected String middleName;
@XmlElement(required = true) final protected List<String> firstName;
@XmlElement(required = true) protected Boolean isMale;
@XmlElement(required = true) protected Date birthday;
//+locale for naming?
```

Writing function or preconditions for `compareTo` method just makes My day ... I'm seriously considering 0 fault tolerance. Yes, meaning existence or lack of apostrophes, whitespace and other symbols or case difference can yield to different results. (And for cynical bastards - this is not homework.)

The question was: **How to store persons name in a record table?**

Comment: +1 for a picture with a sheep in it :-D

Comment: What I'm missing about your question is why do you have such a hard time - I mean, for starters, where is your input coming from, and why do you need to be so bothered about the exact representation? What's bad in having a "name" column and getting it over with?

Comment: Well I though, I would be making my life harder. For example: I might need to search person by its name or family name, sort a table, generate a notification from template where I can use a lable like: `{formal-name}`. Not sure if thy count as valid reasons, but for me, thy do.

Comment: Yes, you are making life harder, because YAGNI.

Comment: @Ishtar Yes. It is called "YAGNI DRY KISS"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [First name, middle name, last name. Why not Full Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122328/first-name-middle-name-last-name-why-not-full-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking for a simple, universal solution, I think you will find that there is none.  Read [this blog posting](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/), and weep.

And when you've finished crying, take a look at [this document](http://enterprisearchitecture.nih.gov/ArchLib/AT/IA/Data/NRFC0002.htm), which attempts to model names for a US American audience.  Obviously it makes a lot of simplifying assumptions, which are probably invalid.

Comment: Dude, I like your answer a lot.

Comment: The "this document" link has suffered link-rot.