# PHP: How can I explode a string by commas, but not wheres the commas are within quotes?

Tags: php, string, explode

I need to explode my string input into an array at the commas. However the string contains commas inside quotes.

Input:

```
$line = 'TRUE','59','A large number is 10,000';

$linearray = explode(",",$line);
$linemysql = implode("','",$linearray);
```

Returns $linemysql as:

```
'TRUE','59','A large number is 10','000'
```

How can I go about accomplishing this, with the explode ignoring the commas inside the quote marks?

Comment: Take a look at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) this should do what you want.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve, I'm asking because I think there is a better way to do it rather than using explode.

Comment: `$line = 'TRUE','59','A large number is 10,000';` is not a string ;)

Comment: In the grand scheme I am trying to take data from a CSV file and dump it into a MySQL database. However there is text containing commas inside some of the array parts that I dont want to seperate.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Since you are using comma seperated values, you can use [`str_getcsv`](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php).

```
str_getcsv($line, ",", "'");
```

Will return:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TRUE
    [1] => 59
    [2] => A large number is 10,000
)
```

Comment: Is there a way to retain those single quotes.

Comment: Add note that the third parameter is a replacement value, I just left it blank "".

Answer (score 6):

It seems you do not want to split your string by commas, but by the succession of quote+comma+quote ?

If so, the [**`preg_split`**](http://fr.php.net/preg_split) function might help, here.

For example, using this portion of code :

```
$line = "'TRUE','59','A large number is 10,000'";
$parts = preg_split("/','/", $line);
var_dump($parts);
```

I get the following output :

```
array
  0 => string ''TRUE' (length=5)
  1 => string '59' (length=2)
  2 => string 'A large number is 10,000'' (length=25)
```

Starting with that, it's now a matter of removing the first and last quotes of the `$line` string, before calling `preg_split` -- as those are delimiters, and don't match the splitting pattern.

Comment: Although what you and others have suggested works, I've realized I'd make a small error. The $line variable does not have quotes marks around its data. Any idea how I would approach the problem now?

Comment: Not valid answer, first segment contains a single quote at starting and last segment at end. same as `explode("','", $line);`