# Split a comma-delimited string (containing values which also contain commas)

Tags: php, preg-replace, explode

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [An explode() function that ignores characters inside quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264775/an-explode-function-that-ignores-characters-inside-quotes)

I have a sample problem. here is is

```
$str = 'field0,field1,field2,"field3a,field3b,field3c",field4,"field5"';
```

I want explode that string to array like this

```
$arr[0] = 'field0';
$arr[1] = 'field1';
$arr[2] = 'field2';
$arr[3] = 'field3a,field3b,field3c';
$arr[4] = 'field4';
$arr[5] = 'field5';
```

Comment: You don't want `explode`, but `str_getcsv`

Comment: possible duplicate of [An explode() function that ignores characters inside quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3264775/an-explode-function-that-ignores-characters-inside-quotes) and [PHP: How can I explode a string by commas, but not wheres the commas are within quotes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132533/php-how-can-i-explode-a-string-by-commas-but-not-wheres-the-commas-are-within-q)

Answer (score 2):

```
$str = 'field0,field1,field2,"field3a,field3b,field3c",field4,"field5"';
$result = str_getcsv($str, ",", "\"");
print_r($result);
```

Prints:

```
Array
(
    [0] => field0
    [1] => field1
    [2] => field2
    [3] => field3a,field3b,field3c
    [4] => field4
    [5] => field5
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Mario's suggestion:  `str_getcsv($str, ',', '"');`

Comment: I missed the double quotes in your example string, thumbs up on Quy's answer.

Comment: field3a, field3b and field3c are example. It could be any words and more than 3 words

Comment: Sorry, I meant indicate thumbs up on Mario's comment.  Look at str_getcsv.  Just pass it comma as the param and " as the enclosure param, and it should automatically parse your data into an array in the way you want.

Comment: This is Not An Answer.  It is a reference to another post on the page and shouldd be removed entirely.

Comment: Actually, no it was a reference to a comment.  The following day, essentially the same answer was provided (my answer works if tested on the input btw)  and received 2 upvotes, with no difference other than the style of quoting used for the arguments (mine was cleaner imnsho).  Some time later the question was closed having found a few relevant duplicates, which is understandable, but given the many ways that this problem might be described, probably should be left as is for the benefit of future search results.