# How to split text in array by comma if comma is in text value

Tags: php

PHP

$str = '0, "Some, text", 0.23, 4';

How to split text to array if the separator ( , ) may be part of value?

Thanks.

Comment: use $new_array = explode(',',$str);  print_r($new_array);

Comment: using `explode(",", $var);`

Comment: It is not an option. $str "contains" 4 values. explode make 5 values!

Comment: @AndrisBriedis try my answer

Comment: Your string looks like comma separated values aka CSV.
You should maybe have a look at the function provided by PHP to parse CSV.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [explode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) for this, the first impresion is that you will indeed get 5 values instead of 4 as you wish.

Your best option would be to use `str_getcsv` ([link](http://au.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php)). Check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5132533/php-how-can-i-explode-a-string-by-commas-but-not-wheres-the-commas-are-within).

Comment: `explode` my friend, not `implode`

Comment: My bad, fixed. Too early here in the morning :)

Comment: Thans for str_getcsv. This is what I needed.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$str = '0, "Some, text", 0.23, 4';
$new = str_getcsv($str, ",","",",");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($new);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => Some, text
    [2] => 0.23
    [3] => 4
)
```

For more info about `str_getcsv` please read http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is, by using explode:

```
$text = "Some, Text";

$parts = explode(", ", $text);
$var1 = array_pop($parts);
$var2 = implode(" ", $parts);

echo "str1: $var1\n";
echo "str2: $var2\n";
```

Will return "str1: Text str2: Some "